# Different ways to connect Signal to Slot

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

The code below creates a `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton`. Pushing the button updates lineedit with a current time. This functionality is achieved by connecting button's 'clicked' signal to lineedit's `update` method using `button.clicked.connect(line.update)`.

[image]

```
import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def update(self, some=None):
        self.setText(str(datetime.datetime.now()))

line = LineEdit()
line.show()

class PushButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent=parent)

button = PushButton()
button.show()

button.clicked.connect(line.update)

app.exec_()
```

Instead of using `button.clicked.connect(line.update)` we could use:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), line.update)`

or

`QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), line, QtCore.SLOT("update()"))`

Alternatively we could declare the button's `customSignal` and connect it to the function we need:

```
import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])


class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update(self, some=None):
        self.setText(str(datetime.datetime.now()))

line = LineEdit()
line.show()


class PushButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    customSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(PushButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        self.customSignal.emit()
        event.ignore()


button = PushButton()
button.show()

button.customSignal.connect(line.update)

app.exec_()
```

Again, instead of using:

`button.customSignal.connect(line.update)`

we could use:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('customSignal()'), line, QtCore.SLOT("update()"))`

Question: Are there any drawbacks of using one approach over another?

Comment: The old syntax is verbose, ugly, and string-centric.  The new syntax is clean, concise, and pythonic.  The new syntax supports everything the old one did.  Go forward... go forward and never look back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SIGNAL/SLOT` examples all use obsolete syntax. This syntax should only be used in the increasingly rare situations where very old versions of PyQt still need to be supported. This means versions prior to 4.5, when the [new-style signal and slot syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) was introduced. You should also be aware that the old-style syntax is no longer forwards-compatible, because PyQt5 does not support it *at all* anymore.

As for the example that overrides `mouseEvent`: it's completely redundant, so I can't imagine there's any **generally** applicable reason to prefer it.

Comment: Thanks for your message! Why would the example that implements a `customSignal` for pushButton and overrides its `mouseEvent` considered redundant?

Comment: @spootnx. I assumed you meant it to be equivalent to the `clicked` signal (like the other examples). In which case, it's redundant in the sense that it's an over-complicated way of achieving something that is already provided by a built-in signal. Of course, as you've written it, the code is not *really* equivalent, because a mouse-press is not the same as a mouse-click. So the custom-signal example could be considered both redundant *and* buggy. (PS: is there a specific reason why you don't want to use the built-in signals?)